# Angular Material Input doesn't show invalid state on async validation

Tags: angular, angular-material

Edited... check Update #1

### Description of the issue

I'm working in a form where I have an async validation for a FormControl that is patched by another FormControl.

I'm using Angular Material with mat-form-field, mat-input and mat-error.

It has two inputs, the first one is to input a business name and it will automatically fill the second input with the slugified version of the name. The second input has an async validation where it checks against the backend if the slug is already in use.

The problem is when the user types a business name which its slug is already in use, the form status is "INVALID" (as expected), however it should display the styling of an invalid input on the second FormControl and it doesn't. If I click on the invalid field and click away it shows the FormControl as invalid but I want that behavior without clicking in the second Control.

[image: Error]

### Expected behavior

If the user types "Test Name" in the business name. The second FormControl show display the slugified version and the input should has the styling of an invalid control. As soon as the user changes the slugified version to "test-name2" it should be valid and show the normal styling for a valid input.

### Example

I've created a Stackblitz where I've set up an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-r9nsk3?file=src/app/app.component.html

### Update #1

For some reason when I tried to bring the proposed solution into my app it still doesn't work. However I could narrow the cause to an Observable.

Before that, let me provide some background. The second FieldControl has an async validator that's called when it changes its value. This validator returns a reference to an Observable which is a property in a Service.

To make it easier, I created a method (On the right side of the GIFS)  that has the call to the backend (Firebase's Callable Function) (it returns Observable<ValidationErrors | null>) or it returns an Observable created with "of" with an initial value set manually (type Observable<ValidationErrors | null>)

Now, let's check both cases:
Case #1 (expected behavior):
When I type the last letter, it marks the FormControl as "INVALID" instantly, shows the field in red, and shows the mat-error with the error message.
[image: test1]

Case #2 (Current behavior):
When I type the last letter, it updates the second field with the slugified version of the first field (as expected). However the FormControl stays in "PENDING" and the input's style doesn't change.
[image: test2]

Finally, I thought the cause was that the Observable didn't finish, but as you can see with the "finalize" operator, both cases display the message confirming that both observables complete.

Comment: The mat-error only displays if the form control has been touched. You can mark your form control as touched programmatically using `this.form.get('businessSlug').markAsTouched();` (after the setValue part in your code).

Comment: To the person who voted that it doesn't have an example. Please don't be an A*$$ because I took my time to create a Stackblitz to show the current behavior.

Comment: @TotallyNewb That seems to be the key. Would you like to answer the question so I can mark it as answered so you can get the reputation?

Comment: Did you by any chance fix your stackblitz that you linked inside of the question? You should make sure that it still reproduces the problem or else it'll confuse future readers. You can make a fork if you want to make adjustments to it.

Comment: No, I haven't changed the stackblitz as far I know.

Answer (score 1):

As per official [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#error-messages):

> Errors are hidden initially and will be displayed on invalid form fields after the user has interacted with the element or the parent form has been submitted.

This means your `FormControl` needs to be marked as touched.

You can do so by programmatically using `this.form.get('businessSlug').markAsTouched();` after you set the value of the control.

Comment: I updated the question... maybe that helps.

Answer (score 1):

update the form input Tuched status here is the updated code

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { filter, map, SubscriptionLike, tap } from 'rxjs';
import { BusinessIdValidator } from './businessId.validator';
import urlSlug from 'url-slug';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  subscriptions$: SubscriptionLike[] = [];

  form = this.fb.group({
    businessName: ['', [Validators.required]],
    businessSlug: ['', [], [BusinessIdValidator.validator()]],
  });

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form.controls.businessName.valueChanges.subscribe((x) => {
      this.form.controls.businessSlug.markAsTouched();
      this.form.controls.businessSlug.setValue(urlSlug(x)); 
    });
  }

 
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tgq492?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2FbusinessId.validator.ts

Comment: I updated the question... maybe that helps.